# Compare two variable string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to compare two strings in javascript. below is my code

```html
var statuss = document.getElementById("status").innerHTML;
```

```
    //alert(statuss);
var s =statuss.toString();
    var ss= "Active";

    if (s === "Active"){
alert ('match');
}
else {
alert ('do not match');
}
```

why am i getting the output " do not match" when it should have been 'match' since when i did

```js
alert ('document.getElementById("status").innerHTML');
```

i got the output: Active. 
So basically both variable should have matched.. why am getting the opposite?

Comment: Can you check your code again? I think some code is missing.

Comment: sory, i've missed a line of code.. i have updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try the following

`var s = statuss.toString().trim();`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that your HTML also contains whitespace at the beginning and/or end.